# in MVC 5 project, "Add view" not showing my models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

My project does not include Entity Framework or any Database, the information is taken from the file system. which mean, a bunch of static folder structure with unknown number of pairs of text files and image. [it supposed to be simple and "stupid"]

I have a static fileHandler class that can read text files and will be used by the `Books` action in `CatalogController` to make a list of objects of bookModel.

I searched everywhere, wrote stuff by the book, using VS2017, built and rebuilt... no errors. yet, When right clicking the action, in "Add View" dialog there's none of my models.

Theory: do I HAVE TO use db??

I hope I'm clear enough, i haven't touched code for over 4 years now..

Btw, I know I can write everything by hand and ignore structure etc... but, before I turn "barbaic", is there a solution?

Thank You :)

Comment: Just choose "Empty (without model)", then when the view gets generated manually put `@model Web.ViewModels.MyModel` (where Web.ViewModel.MyModel is the fully qualified name of your model) at the top of the view. Thats what I always do anyways, you should be fine. For some reason maybe Visual Studio isn't finding your Models. This should have nothing to do with whether or not you are using a dB.

Comment: @zgood is right here and some how i believe you should check weither the class files(model) are included in your project since you said you are taking from folder structure means you are bringing them from external and not creating them in the model folder itself

Comment: The Data is received from the simple text files, which aren't there yet but the model is there, in the Models folder.